# C# with Gridview, Access, DateTime and converting

Tags: c#, database, string, datetime, gridview

I have been going through the motions and still cannot seem to get this right. I have textboxes in a gridview that are populated from an access database. They are all datetime values. In the backend code, I am trying to loop through all those values and then apply conditional formatting. For some unknown reason I am unable to get the value from those textboxes in the gridview and when I do, they are seen by the app as string as opposed to datetime. Converting is futile as the same error, "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." keeps popping up.

Any ideas on how to get values from a gridview textbox, and then convert them from a string to a datetime format?

Here is the code thus far...

```
for (int p = 0; p < rowscount; p++)
 {
     var myLabel2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[p].Cells[0].FindControl("Label2");
     var myLabel4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[p].Cells[0].FindControl("Label4");

     DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(myLabel2.Text).Date;
     DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;
     DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(myLabel4.Text).Date;

     if (now >= start && now <= end)
     {
         myLabel2.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
         myLabel4.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
         myLabel7.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
         myLabel9.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
     }
     else
     {
         myLabel2.BackColor = Color.White;
         myLabel4.BackColor = Color.White;
         myLabel7.BackColor = Color.White;
         myLabel9.BackColor = Color.White;
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show sample `myLabel2.Text` or `myLabel4.Text` which you intend to convert ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like datetime format issue. Your GridView converts datetime into string in one way and you're trying to convert it back to datetime using different format. Instead of `Convert.ToDateTime` try using [`DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Use format that applies to your case.

Comment: ...and if the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" still pops up?

Comment: Maybe then it is not a datetime string at all. Step through the code to find out.

Comment: If not, what format could it be? Could it be a problem with the population from the database? Stepping through the code, does not reveal much...

Comment: String can be a wrong data, non datetime for example. What is the value of `myLabel2.Text` before you try to convert it to datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Are the textboxes both in the first column of `GridView1`? For the code:

```
var myLabel2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[p].Cells[0].FindControl("Label2");
var myLabel4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[p].Cells[0].FindControl("Label4");
```

It means the names of your textboxes are "Label2" and "Label4", and they are both in the first column as you use `Cells[0]` to fetch them. Your have to make sure of that.

You can add break point to the above code, and debug it. You can see if  `myLabel2` and `myLabel4` have any value.

Comment: Yeah, both textboxes are in the first column and both have values... the string in the textboxes are "2012/04/03 12:00:00 AM", is there was way to convert this string to a datetime format?

Comment: Yes, both `Convert.ToDateTime` and `DateTime.Parse` can convert this kind of format of string. Which line cause the error?

Comment: DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider); This seems to be the line causing the problem. The actual value of dateString seems to be in contention....

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(myLabel2.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".. still to no avail.... could this be a problem with the actual database field?